# blinds 3000/6000 one player is allin for 4000 another raises 15000 all players fold the big and small blinds how much can the all in win

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

the blinds are 3000/6000 one player goes all in for 4000 another player raises to 15000 all other players fold including the big and small blinds. how much can the all in player win.

Answer (score 0):

The all-in player can only win the size of his stack from any other player, including the blinds. This means he can only win 4000 from the Big Blind. The other 2000 from the Big Blind goes into the side pot.

The main pot (which the all-in player can win) will therefore be 3000 + (4000 x 3) = 15000. The raiser automatically wins the side pot (the remaining 2000 from the Big Blind, plus the rest of his 15000 raise returned).